# Parsing / Decoding an NNTP Newsgroup article with corresponding content-type

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, nntp, newsgroup

I am still on trying to create my android newsreader for my university's newsgroup server and once again I am stuck. I am currently using the Apache NNTPClient Library for all of my network calls. 
I manage to receive the messages and everything is fine except for proper proper article decoding.

I have little to no clue how I should go about dealing with all the different `Content-type` attributes that a newsgroup article can be written in. Is there any Java library that already does this in order to get properly encoded Java strings or the content of multipart messages? Is there any way of using the javax.mail Api to parse all the possible response formats?

I am really glad for every piece of information you guys can share with me as it is a more or less dead technology and retrieving documentation and help is cumbersome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Newsgroup articles are MIME messages, which JavaMail can parse using the [MimeMessage constructor](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#MimeMessage-javax.mail.Session-java.io.InputStream-).  That will allow you to access all the header fields as well as the content of the message.  For text content, you can get the content as a String, which you can then display or manipulate however you want.  For non-text content, you can get the raw data as an InputStream, or save the content to a file.

How to display the many different MIME types of content is a whole separate problem, which depends heavily on what type of application you're writing.

Comment: Thank you @BillShannon that was exactly what I wanted to know. The `getInputStream()` should lead to the results is that right? ..  Yeah sure sorry for not being clear.. i only am looking for some kind of right encoded String I can save without weird encoding problems.. I think this can be accomplished that way.

Comment: The getInputStream method will get you the original data, decoded.  If that's the "result" you wanted, you're all set!

Comment: Alright. My last question is.. do I have to take care of anything when trying to turn the Reader that is returned from the NNTPClient to a inputstream the mimemessage can use?

Comment: MimeMessage is expecting an InputStream of ASCII (usually) bytes.  If you have a Reader, and the it's returning characters that all happen to be ASCII, you should be able to easily write an InputStreamFilter that turns them into bytes.  If it's returning the full range of Unicode characters, it's going to be a bit more difficult.  If performance is not a concern, you have one thread read the characters and write them into a Writer wrapped around a PipedOutputStream, and another thread pass the PipedInputStream to the MimeMessage constructor.

Comment: Okay I am sorry for still keeping this up but I am not able to fix my problem.. I am trying something [like in this code snippet] (https://pastebin.com/t4DPT9F9) but i am still messing something up ...Please help if you can :)

Comment: I think you need to read [this JavaMail FAQ entry](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#mainbody).  Look at some of the [JavaMail sample programs](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/#Samples) while you're at it.